# Can Arbitrum's block timestamp be trusted to the same degree as the L1 time?

Tags: timestamp, layer-2, arbitrum, l2

L1 blocks [cannot be fudged](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/135445/24693) by validators. It is a value that can be safely used by apps.

Can that be said about the value of `block.timestamp` on a L2 like Arbitrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block timestamp cannot be trusted to the same degree on a L2 like Arbitrum, but it is not fully gameable.

Whenever a batch settles on the L1, it sends the latest timestamp to the L2.

From the [Arbitrum docs](https://docs.arbitrum.io/for-devs/concepts/differences-between-arbitrum-ethereum/block-numbers-and-time#timestamp-boundaries-of-the-sequencer):

> to limit the degree to which the sequencer can adjust timestamps, some boundaries are set, currently to 24 hours earlier than the current time, and 1 hour in the future

Kudos to [Fred](https://twitter.com/0x66726564) for helping me understand how this works.